How to access files from public directory in NextJS
I want to create a link inside my nextjs application that when clicked opens up the file. I want to create a json file at my.domain.com/.well-known/file.json.  I have created the folder in public directory and done this structure same as but I am getting 404 | Page Not Found error when I open the link for file.
My environment: NextJs - 14.0.4  Npm - 10.2.4  Node - v21.5.0 
This link is required for enabling deep links in our application.
My file structure:
|-- project
  |-- public
    |-- .well-known
      |-- file.json


You need to provide a lot more information for people to be able to help, but if your file structure really does match the url you're trying to reach, it could be an issue with a hidden file since you added a period in front of the file.

I added the period as I need the structure to be exactly same as that. Its for deep links verification on google play store.

The issue was in my middleware handling the internationalization of the NextJs app, I made an exclusion in middleware.ts file and the route started working.
Took me 10 hours to figure out, hope it helps anyone searching around :)
